# When does a topological space inherit multiplication from a dense subspace?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Suppose $K$ is a compact topological Hausdorff space with a dense subspace $G$.

Moreover, let $G$ have a group structure which is compatible with the topology inherited from $K$.  i.e.  $G$ is a topological group with the subspace topology.

Is it known under what circumstances will ensure that the multiplication can be extended continuously to all of $K$? or does the answer depend on the group?

Comment: As a simple example: let $K = S^1$, and $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$. Morally this is like adjoining $\pm \infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If we try and continuously extend addition to $S^1 \times S^1$ we have that $x + \infty = \infty + x = \infty$ is the only continuous choice for $x \neq \infty$, however $\infty + \infty$ admits no continuous choice of result. Finally, note that $\infty$ has no inverse and fails the cancellation law.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: You can embed $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ as a dense subgroup of the circle group $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ (by mapping $q$ to $e^{iq}$ say). Also (following JHance's idea) you can embed $\mathbb{Q}$ as a dense subset of $S^1$ such that the addition operation on the image of $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be extended to a group operation on $S^1$. So the answer depends not only on $G$ but on how it is embedded in $K$.

Comment: If $G$, with the relative topology, is pseudocompact and $K$ is the Stone-Čech compactification of $G$, then the operation on $G$ extends to $K$ making it into a topological group. This uses a theorem of Glicksberg and the fact that $G\times G$ is pseudocompact if $G$ is a pseudocompact group (this can be found in Hewitt-Ross, according to my notes). Sorry, but I have no reference for the theorem of Glicksberg, except my notes for an exam of “some” years ago.

Comment: Thank you Greg, this is exactly what I was seeking.  Thank you!

Comment: A reference for  the fact that the product of an arbitrary family of pseudocompact topological
groups is pseudocompact is W. W. Comfort, Kennet A. Ross, *Pseudocompactness an uniform continuity in topological groups*, Pacif. J. Math. **16**:3 (1966), 483-496.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple counter example, take $G=(0,1)$ and $K=[0,1]$. Then, $G$ is homeomorphic to $(0,\infty)$ which has a multiplicative group structure that pulls back to $G$ as
$$m:G\times G\to G,\quad m(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right).$$
Now it is clear that $m$ does not extend to $K$.